# How to grab text from Kick Starter using XPath in Google Sheets

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I am attempting to extract location data from Kick Starter to add to my existing data-set.

Currently I am using Google Sheets along with XPath to grab various elements and am only having trouble with the text element of the location.

It looks something like the following:

```
A1 = https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1201626825/tori-scott-live-at-the-edinburgh-fringe-festival?ref=home_new_and_noteworthy
A2 = //a[@class="nowrap navy-700 flex items-center medium type-12"]/text()
IMPORTXML(A1, $A$2)
```

Oddly enough regardless of whether I put in the `text()` element or not, I get an Imported content is empty error.

I have also:

- Grabbed the entire list element (Promoted status, category, location) with success
- Tried extracting the exact location with the empty content error

Comment: Did my answer work? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

How about this answer? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Part 1 :

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML(A1, "//div[@class='block-lg hide']//div[@class='NS_projects__badges mb3']//div[@class='border-top border-bottom border-top-none-md border-none-lg nested-full-width-xs nested-full-width-sm nested-full-width-md mb4 mb5-sm mb0-md']//div[@class='grid-row']//div[@class='col-sm-22-24 col-offset-sm-1-24 col-offset-md-0-24']//div[@class='py2 py3-lg flex']//div[@class='flex items-center auto-scroll-x']"), 6)
```

or

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML(A1, "//div[@class='block-lg hide']//div//div//div//div//div//div"), 6)
```

#### Part 2 :

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML(A1, "//div[@class='col-full']//div[@class='NS_projects__badges mb3']//div[@class='border-top border-bottom border-top-none-md border-none-lg nested-full-width-xs nested-full-width-sm nested-full-width-md mb4 mb5-sm mb0-md']//div[@class='grid-row']//div[@class='col-sm-22-24 col-offset-sm-1-24 col-offset-md-0-24']//div[@class='py2 py3-lg flex']//div[@class='flex items-center auto-scroll-x']"), 6)
```

or

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML(A1, "//div[@class='col-full']//div//div//div//div//div//div"), 6)
```

#### Result :

```
Edinburgh, UK
```

#### Note :

- There are 2 parts of `@class="nowrap navy-700 flex items-center medium type-12"` in the HTML. I was not sure the part you want. So here, I would like to propose 2 parts.
- It supposes that `https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1201626825/tori-scott-live-at-the-edinburgh-fringe-festival?ref=home_new_and_noteworthy` is in a cell A1.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.